# Search content of a JSON file with output in a DataGridView

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

The Form has a text field and a DataGridView. It is necessary, without displaying the entire contents of the JSON file in the DataGridView, to search the content of the JSON file and display the search result in the DataGridView.
You need to search by the UserName tag. You need to start typing either the first or last name in the text field and in the DataGridView display the result of the found.

How to read text file in DataGridView I know:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Users))(File.ReadAllText("D:\Users.json"))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = result
    End Sub

      Public Class Users
        Public Property ID() As Integer
        Public Property UserName() As String
        Public Property Login() As String
        Public Property Title() As String
        Public Property Dep() As String
        Public Property Mail() As String
        Public Property Phone() As String
    End Class
End Class
```

I also know how to do a file search. Only for some reason the result displays - the first element found:

```
Dim json As String = File.ReadAllText("D:\Users.json")
Dim objectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Users))(json)
Dim foundItem = objectList.Where(Function(underscore) underscore.UserName.Contains("Tom")).FirstOrDefault()

If foundItem IsNot Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show(foundItem.UserName)
Else
    MsgBox("none")
End If
```

And the actual contents of the json file itself:

```json
[
{
"id":"1",
"UserName":"Fred Smith",
"Login":"f.smith",
"Title":"engineer",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"f.smith@domain.com",
"Phone":"111",
},
{
"id":"2",
"UserName":"Ben Taylor",
"Login":"b.taylor",
"Title":"programmer",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"b.taylor@domain.com",
"Phone":"100",
},
{
"id":"3",
"UserName":"Steve Harris",
"Login":"s.harris",
"Title":"System Administrator",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"s.harris@domain.com",
"Phone":"263",
},
{
"id":"4",
"UserName":"Tom Walker",
"Login":"t.walker",
"Title":"engineer",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"t.walker@domain.com",
"Phone":"263",
},
{
"id":"5",
"UserName":"Tom Davis",
"Login":"t.davis",
"Title":"engineer",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"t.davis@domain.com",
"Phone":"200",
},
{
"id":"6",
"UserName":"Ben Walker",
"Login":"b.walker",
"Title":"System Administrator",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"b.walker@domain.com",
"Phone":"167",
},
]
```

Comment: You have `.FirstOrDefault()` after the `.Where()` clause, so that query returns just the first match found. -- Note that the `If` condition right after is expecting this kind of result. -- You usually filter the data source to only show results that match some criteria. I suggest to use a BindingSource, since it can also be used as filter.

Comment: I would be grateful if you provide an example in the form of code. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify whether this is some kind of *assignment*, because - as it's written - it looks like one. It doesn't matter much, per se, the question is written well enough, but if that is the case, you may need to use specific tools. Is a BindingSource included?

Comment: Is it possible to do this without binding to the BindingSource?
Since the data display mode may change. This is not a job, this is for yourself.

Comment: There's no relation between a BindingSource and the way the data is presented.

Comment: did not know.
I would be grateful if you show how my problem can be solved with code.

Comment: All right. To make it shorter, your JSON could be deserialized to a DataTable (since, well, it is actually a data table). This would simplify the whole thing, because a `List(Of T)` has no means to either sort or filter a complex object (as a Class object), so you have to add it yourself, while a DataTable already implements these functionalities. If you're ok with that, I'll post an example.

Comment: Well thank you. I would be grateful for an example. I also ask you to publish an example through the BindingSource, if not difficult. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note:

- The JSON presented here represent an array of objects which all have the same properties. It can be considered an array of *records* or *Rows*.
- You need to deserialize this JSON, present the result in a DataGridView and allow the user to filter and probably sort the data.

You're currently deserializing this JSON to simple collection a class objects, which is perfectly fine. It may become a little more complex if you want to filter and sort this collection, since a simple `List<T>` doesn't support it by itself. Nor does a BindingList.
You should implement the [IBindingListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ibindinglistview) interface in a class that handles the List of objects and most probably also the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface in the base class (your current `Users` class).
Or use an ORM / Mini-ORM instead.

There's an already built (and tested) Type that already implements all these features, the [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable) class.
Since, as mentioned, your JSON IS actually a Table (an array of *records*), deserializing it to a DataTable is quite straightforward. It's just:

```
Dim dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json)
```

The DataTable class already allows filtering, setting its [DefaultView.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter) property and sorting, setting its [DefaultView.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.sort) property.

Nonetheless, I suggest to use a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) as *mediator* between the DataTable and the UI.
This tool is quite useful, since it provides common methods to filter and sort a source of data, provided that the source of data actually has these capabilities.
Using a BindingSource, you always use the same methods, no matter what the source of data is.
It also generates some useful events, as the [ListChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.listchanged), [AddingNew](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.addingnew), [CurrentChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.currentchanged) events and more.
The `ListChanged` event also provides arguments that specify the type of change.

With a BindingSource, to serialize back to JSON, if the the data has changed:

```
[BindingSource].EndEdit()
Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject([BindingSource].DataSource, Formatting.Indented)
```

---

In the sample code, these objects are used (see the visual example):

- `UsersSource`: the BindingSource object
- `tBoxFilterUser`: a TextBox Control, filters the data using the `UserName` Property
- `tBoxFilterTitle`: a TextBox Control, filters the data using the `Title` Property
- `btnRemoveFilter`: a Button Control used to remove the current filters
- `dgv`: a DataGridView Control

```
Public Class SomeForm

    Private UsersSource As New BindingSource()
    ' Current filters
    Private UserNameFilter As String = "UserName LIKE '%%'"
    Private UserTitleFilter As String = "Title LIKE '%%'"

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)

        Dim json = File.ReadAllText("D:\Users.json")
        Dim dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json)
        dt.AcceptChanges()
        UsersSource.DataSource = dt
        dgv.DataSource = UsersSource
    End Sub

    Private Sub tBoxFilterUser_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tBoxFilterUser.TextChanged
        Dim tbox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        UserNameFilter = $"UserName LIKE '%{tbox.Text}%'"
        UsersSource.Filter = $"{UserNameFilter} AND {UserTitleFilter}"
    End Sub

    Private Sub tBoxFilterTitle_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tBoxFilterTitle.TextChanged
        Dim tbox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        UserTitleFilter = $"Title LIKE '%{tbox.Text}%'"
        UsersSource.Filter = $"{UserNameFilter} AND {UserTitleFilter}"
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRemoveFilter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemoveFilter.Click
        tBoxFilterUser.Clear()
        tBoxFilterTitle.Clear()
        UsersSource.RemoveFilter()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

This is how it works:

[image: JSON to DataTable]

Comment: Very cool. Thanks a lot for the example!

Comment: Well, it's a working example :) Give it a try, see whether this can work for you.

Comment: Of course, this is already a different topic, but can you tell me how to set the column type before adding data from the json file.

Comment: Can you specify what kind of problem you need to solve (in relation to what you posted here)? Do you need to change the Type of a Property in your JSON, or change the Type of a Column after? In this case, to what and why? -- If the explanation is too long for comments, post a new question and point to this question as reference.

Comment: That is, changing the type of DataTable does not work when loading a json file? Tell me, how can I change the column type after loading?

Comment: Do you mean the Type of a Column in a DataTable? You can change the Type of a Column when the DataTable has no data yet. Not after, unless you build a new DataTable and convert the data to a different Type using the original DataTable as source. But you can change the Type of Property in your JSON. E.g., now the `id` is a string Type. You can change it to Long removing the double quotes on the value. -- You need to be specific, describe what you want to change and into what and possibly why.

Comment: I understand. My mistake.
I will try to describe in detail. There is a class with custom column type in datagridview. To display text and pictures in cells. Link to class below. So I want that when loading data from a json file in the usrName column, a picture and a username are displayed.
[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1taQ406ZJVF3UMr9THlHbTZ9t3RUoz9ZP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It's not clear then what Type you want to change and into what, where the images are coming from or how the DataGridView is designed. The JSON you have posted doesn't contain images or base64 strings. You have to post a new question, with all details needed to understand what you're trying to do, what tools you're working with and how the custom DataGridViewColumn is involved or meant to be used, with what source of data.